# MS access Query with in and parameter

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a query in MS access where the parameter is a list (given by me).

This works `In ("2209487";"2102669";"2727930";"3727550")`, but if I try to put a parameter inside the "IN" like this: In ([NUM]) It doesn't return a result!
I write `2209487";"2102669";"2727930";"3727550` when the parameter window appears.

PS: my laptop is in European Portuguese so I use the ";"

Comment: Element array for IN() cannot be dynamic in query object. This requires VBA. Either apply criteria to form or report filter or use QueryDefs to modify query object.

Comment: Hi June7. Thanks for your help. it prevented me of wasting a lot of time in impossible scenario. Cheers Jorge

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a "list" or "multiple" values for this. But you CAN do this in the where clause of hte form (or report).

First, remove any paramters for the form/report. You want to be able to open/launch the form/report WITHOUT any prompts from the query. In fact, what follows will even work if you based the form/report directly on the table.

So, you can do this:

```
dim strInvoices    as string

strInvoices = InputBox("Enter invoice numbers ',' between each")

dim strWhere as string

strWhere = "InvoiceNumber in (" & strInvoices & ")"

docmd.OpenReport "frmInvoices",,,strWhere
```

So, you can provide a list as per above and use the "in"

the IN clause is this

```
  InvoiceNumber in (234,433,555)
```

So, you can pass the conditions as a "where" clause to a open form or report.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!!!!

i've redone the query and logic of the database) in another way.